# How pass fragment arguments while using a view pager with different fragments/layouts?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

**Objective**: To use fragment arguments to pass along the string value from a `TextView` to a new fragments `TextView`, BUT while using a `ViewPager` with different `layouts/fragments` in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`.

**Problem**: The new fragment never receives the fragments arguments from the previous fragment.

**My Set up**: I have my `Activity` hosting the `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. I have overridden `FragmentPagerAdapters` `getItem(int position)` method to create a new `fragment` instance depending on the current position of the `ViewPager`. Right now I only have two `Fragments` in my adapter, but will be adding more after getting over this obstacle. I am using the `newInstance()` technique to pass along the `Fragment`'s arguments, but nothing is ever passed.

**Pertinent Code**:

My FragmentPagerAdapter code:

```
//this is a variable that I pass in as the newInstanct() methods parameter,
// I update   this variable from my fragments constantly
public static String fragmentArgumentsValue = "";

mViewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {


            @Override
            public int getCount() {

                return NUMBER_OF_VIEWS;
            }

            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Log.d(TAG, "---In getPosition(), position 0---");

                    return Frag1
                            .newInstance(fragmentArgumentsValue);

                case 1:
                    Log.d(TAG, "---In getPosition(), position 1---");

                    return frag2
                            .newInstance(fragmentArgumentsValue);

                default:
                    Log.d(TAG, "---In getPosition(), DEFAULT---");

                    return frag1
                            .newInstance(fragmentArgumentsValue);
                }

            }
        });
```

One of the fragments newInstance() method:

```
public static Fragment newInstance(String fragmentArgumentsValue) {
    Frag1 f = new Frag1();
    Bundle bun = new Bundle();
    bun.putString(KEY_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS_STRING, fragmentArgumentsValue);
    f.setArguments(bun);
    return f;
}
```

Getting the fragments arguments:

```
String argString = getArguments().getString(
        KEY_FRAGMENT_ARGUMENTS_STRING);
if (argString.length() != 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Trying to set the frag args to:" + argString);
    mWorkingTextView.setText("" + argString);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Couldn't set frag args to: " + argString);
}
```

**What I've Tried**: I've tried giving the `Activity` that hosts the `ViewPager` and `FragmentPagerAdapter` a `static` variable that I constantly update in each one of my `fragments`, I include the `static` variable in the `fragment.newInstance(staticVariableInActivity)` method, but this doesn't seem to work.
I've also tried using the `ViewPager` callback `viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener()` I had overridden the `onPageSelected(int pos)` and tried to pass the fragment arguments there, nevertheless it didn't work... so please help me S.O.!!!

**My thoughts**: I do not have the different `fragments` and `layouts` in an `ArrayList` or any list for that matter, I just instantiate the `Fragments` via the `newInstance()` method depending on the positions of the `FragementPagerAdapter`, could this be a problem? Should I create a `singleton` list of the `layouts/fragments`? So I can change the values of the `Fragments` `TextViews` via the `singleton` list? (excuse me if that's a dumb or not possible thing to do).

**Note**: I am am saving away the TextViews values via `public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` to handle screen rotations. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so I this link will help in the communication between fragments: [Communication with other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) .

You need to define a interface that the Activity will implement and the fragments will use to send data onward to the activity, and the activity will then find the fragment by tag doing something like this:

```
frag = (Fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentByTag(
                            "android:switcher:" + R.id.viewPager + ":2");
```

and then update the fragment by calling a public method implemented within the fragment.

The link provided will help greatly, it is from the Android Development website.

Answer (score 2):

Adds the bundle inside your Adapter.

example in the constructor of the adapter :

```
      public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        fragments.add(TileFragments.newInstance());
        Bundle bundleFeatures = new Bundle();
        bundleFeatures.putString(ContentName.FEATURES.toString(),ContentName.FEATURES.toString());

        fragments.get(0).setArguments(bundleFeatures);

    }
```